# Writing array combinations when sizes are arbitrary

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations, permutation

Consdering the following input:

```
[
  // all inner arrays have the same size
  ["en","play","checkers"]
  ["pt","jogar","damas"]
]
```

Also considering the following ouput:

```
en/play/checkers
en/play/damas
en/jogar/checkers
en/jogar/damas
pt/play/checkers
pt/play/datas
pt/jogar/checkers
pt/jogar/damas
```

That means I combined both arrays and generate multiple strings. If you look at the input as a matrix, you will notice that combinations are never made among different columns (e.g. /en/chess/play). That is a column restriction.

When we know the number of arrays (2) and their size (3), the algorithm would be something like:

```
for i=0 ; i<3; i++
  for j=0; j<3; j++
    for k=0; k<3; k++
       matrix[i][j][k]
```

Q: But how do I write an algorithm that works for any number of arrays (N) of any fixed size (K)?

Comment: Use recursion. I could probably show you an example of what I mean but there are no data types given or even a programming language mentioned.

Comment: Because it is not a specific language problem.

Comment: Indeed, so my previous suggestion should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the single-word suggestion :)

Comment: I would say that it is the the Cartesian product of each choice of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you transpose the input first:

```
[
 ["en", "pt"],
 ["play", "jogar"],
 ["checkers", "damas"],
]
```

Now you can write a recursive function that given this 2D array:

a) Loops through each value of the last array, appending it to a string array as a parameter

b) Calls itself with the last array removed from the 2D array

c) Base case is if the array is empty, then return the string array.